# Child component not updating when data chaining - why does :key need to be the value that changes?

Tags: vuejs2

I had a table row that was like this:

```
   <tr v-for="(pricing, idx) in pricings"">
     <td>{{pricing.description}}</td>
     <td>$ {{pricing.unconfirmed_price_formatted}}
   </tr>
```

I wanted to migrate this table row to a component. However, when I change the underlying data (this.pricings), the child component doesn't update. I am calling it like this:

```
   <pricing-row v-for="(pricing, idx) in pricings" :key="pricing.id + pricing.description" :pricing=pricing v-on:updateAfterSave="savedData" v-on:showModal="showAddEditModal"></pricing-row>
```

The strange thing is that the underlying array is changing - just this component is not properly updating.

It's also clear that if we use as a `key` the value that changes (unconfirmed_price_formatted in this case), it does update.

I'm a bit baffled by this behavior. Any ideas on what is wrong?

#### edit 1

here is the component:

```
<template>
  <tr>
    <td>{{localPricing.description}}</td>
    <td v-if="localPricing.price">$ {{localPricing.price_formatted}} {{localPricing.units_display}}</td>
    <td v-else>&nbsp;</td>
    <td v-if="localPricing.unconfirmed_price">$ {{localPricing.unconfirmed_price_formatted}} {{localPricing.unconfirmed_units_display}}</td>
    <td v-else>&nbsp;</td>
    <td v-if="localPricing.state != 'deleted'">
      <!-- button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" @click="willShowModalWithBattery(pricing)">edit</button -->
      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" @click="showModal(pricing)">edit</button>
    </td>
    <td v-else>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: ['pricing'],
  data: function(){
    return {
      localPricing: this.pricing
    }
  },
  methods:{
    showModal: function(pricing){
      this.$emit('showModal', pricing);
    }

  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Show the component definition, specifically its `props`.

Comment: @Marty - I just added to the key the part that changes `unconfirmed_price_formatted` and now it updates! What is going on with this behavior? will add component

Comment: Personally I would have made `:key="idx"`.

Comment: thx @Marty I should mention I'm just learnign Vuejs so appreciate any missteps on my part.  I had it as `:key="idx"` but wasn't working, adding that part that actually changes causes it to work though. Really confounding behavior.

Comment: Do you get better results if you declare your `props` as `props: { pricing: { type: Object, required: true } }`?

Comment: thx for idea @Marty but still not updating. hmm... so experimentally, it seems like I need to use the exact element that changes as part of the `:key` - this is confirmed by looking at the vue inspector.  I guess I'm just really confused if this is intended behavior or I'm just not getting it.

Comment: you should be able to set :key='idx' without an issue. i'm pretty sure that you're losing reactivity because you're setting localPricing: this.pricing in data. try either using pricing directly in the template or creating a computed property localPricing _=> this.pricing and see if that'll help.